# Webbrowser component - manipulation with source html

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

Friend of mine is playing some internet game. It's mainly text game. No animations, no videos, just text and couple of images.

He would like to have some more possibilities like enhanced ingame notepad etc.

**My question** is, what webbrowser (IE based/chrome/...) component should I use, if I need easy manipulation with source code of the webbrowser, meaning simple access to source html code, reading and mainly inserting a bits of my own html code to existing?

Example

When user navigates to this page

```
<h1>blahblah</h1>
<div>
<table></table>
</div>
```

I want to remove table from page, insert my own enhanced table and than refresh page using same css style like origin page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/#download) would allow you to do it, and it's a fast and very functional embed-able component.

Comment: Is it working on 64bit OS? Since I couldn't see it in their download section, I'm not sure about it ...

Comment: Ok, I will wait 24 hours for another opinions then try it and post report.